# _.forEach loop value change all inherited data

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying nested 2 _.forEach;

```
_.forEach(this.operationTypes, (value: any, key) => {
  value.Terms = [];
  this.operationLimits.push(value);
  _.forEach(this.operationTerms, (subValue: OperationTerm, subKey) => {
    let typeTerms = _.filter(this.operationTypeTerms, { OperationType: { Id: value.Id }, OperationTerm: { Id: subValue.Id } });
    subValue.TypeTerms = typeTerms[0];
    this.operationLimits[key].Terms.push(subValue);
  });
});
```

But it creates all `TypeTerms` values same as last loop's values. 
That means the new values are inherited from my foreach loops `subValue`, if the `subValue` changed, all assigned from this going to be changed automatically.

How to prevent that?

Thanks

Edit:

It supposed to be like this.

```
[
{
 Active: true,
 Id: 2,
 Name: "Cash Out",
 Terms: [
  {
   Id: 2,
   Name: "Daily Limit",
   TypeTerms: "Forbidden" -> all of these are same 'forbidden', but it could be 'forbidden' or 'allowed'. At the end of the loop all data changed to forbidden, because the last datas TypeTerms value is 'forbidden'
  },
  {
   Id: 3,
   Name: "Weekly Limit",
   TypeTerms: "Forbidden"
  }
 ]
},
{
 Active: true,
 Id: 3,
 Name: "Top Up",
 Terms: [
  {
   Id: 2,
   Name: "Daily Limit",
   TypeTerms: "Forbidden"
  },
  {
   Id: 3,
   Name: "Weekly Limit"
   TypeTerms: "Forbidden"
  }
 ]
}
]
```

Comment: Two nested loops and a filter seems like a candidate for a refactor.  Can you provide a small sample of your input data and your desired output?

Comment: Updated on base entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Without knowing the input params of operationTerms, operationTypes &
  operationTypeTerms, its tough to produce the required output. However
  based on the question logic & provided output I assumed the input to
  bring the result you are seeking.
- Please note that I've used simple underscore here and no angular but
  that shouldn't affect the logic nevertheless

```js
operationTypes = [{
  "Active": true,
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Cash Out"
}, {
  "Active": true,
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "Top Up"
}]

operationTerms = [{
  Id: 2,
  Name: "Daily Limit"
}, {
  Id: 3,
  Name: "Weekly Limit"
}]

operationTypeTerms = [{
  "operationTypeId": 2,
  "operationTermId": 2,
  TypeTerms: ["Forbidden"]
}, {
  "operationTypeId": 3,
  "operationTermId": 3,
  TypeTerms: ["Allowed", "Forbidden"]
}, {
  "operationTypeId": 3,
  "operationTermId": 2,
  TypeTerms: ["Forbidden"]
}, {
  "operationTypeId": 2,
  "operationTermId": 3,
  TypeTerms: ["Allowed", "Forbidden"]
}]


var result = [];
_.each(operationTypes, function(type) {
  var typeObj = _.extend(type, {});
  var terms = [];
  _.each(operationTerms, function(term) {
    var val = _.extend(term, {});
    var typeTermObj = _.filter(operationTypeTerms, {
      operationTypeId: type.Id,
      operationTermId: term.Id
    });
    val.TypeTerms = typeTermObj[0].TypeTerms[0];
    terms.push(val);
  });
  typeObj.Terms = terms;
  result.push(typeObj)
});

$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Yes. It works! All the important point that create new instance like operationTypeId: type.Id, operationTermId: term.Id